# Aren't the servers that store MYSQL database in Facebook down for maintenance ever as Facebook is always on?

Tags: distributed-systems, databases

I have never seen my account not being able to login!

Comment: A reminder that, as our [help/on-topic] states, "Questions about how a particular piece of software or hardware works aren't science (unless you're asking about the scientific concepts behind that software or hardware). You may ask on Super User or other appropriate technology sites."  With this short question, it's hard to know what kind of answer will best fit your current level of understanding.  In the future I encourage you to provide additional context, if you can; see [this page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The databases of any large service are replicated across many machines. This means that the service itself will be available unless many of those machines fail simultaneously, which is very unlikely.  Also, by spreading those machines around the world, it becomes very unlikely that something like a power cut will take out all the servers; it also means that customers in Australia don't have lots of lag from having to authenticate against a server in the USA, for example).

Comment: Thats's really great. But how does one server communicated for the other for data?